Can we change Owner of Product Request standard object in Field Service Lightning App
I am working in FSL project. I can change Owner of Product Request record in desktop as field technician but I am not able to do that in FSL mobile app. User has create and edit access on object plus it has transfer record system permission. Dont know whether its feasible or not in fsl mobile. I have also created one custom field service mobile flow and used it in the action and its also working in desktop browser but its not working in mobile.
If anyone has worked or have any idea please let me know the approach.
Adding to this if we can use standard Change Owner functionality in fsl mobile app that would be great..But as of now I could not able to show that in tje fsl mobile app.
Thank you
